# US date format with two digits for month and day

Tags: c#, date, datetime, .net-core, date-formatting

I want to get the date in US format i.e. MM/dd/yyyy on .NET core.
That is month first, then day and next year. Month and Day in 2 digits.
I need this date in datetime data type not as a string.
Please help.
I tried following (C#)

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact("07/31/2022","MM/dd/yyyy",null)
```

but startDate comes as 7/31/2022. Month not in two digits. I want startDate as 07/31/2022

Comment: C# in .net core

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact("07/31/2022","M/dd/yyyy",null)`

Comment: A `DateTime` has no format. If you want it to *display* with two-digit months after parsing, you have to use an appropriate format string in a `.ToString()` or `.Format()` method, otherwise you get the default for your system. For example, on my system I get `2022-07-31 00:00:00`.

Comment: ps. Just to check; when you say "startDate comes as 7/31/2022"; do you mean the output?  `startDate` is a datetime; so you don't need to worry about it's format; it's a value rather than a formatted value.  You only care about the format if converting it back to string; in which case you can format it there; i.e.: `var startDateFormatted = startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Thanks. I got the point. Actually this problem came with a SOAP API call where it expects the value as a datetime in MM/dd/yyyy format. Anyway I managed it in XML level by passing value as a string.